# inserting and getting from Cassandra with Composite Key: InvalidRequestException(why:Not enough bytes to read value of component 0)

Tags: cassandra, thrift, composite-key

I'm trying to insert into a Column Family with a composite Key using thrift in Java. I get the following exception:

```
 InvalidRequestException(why:Not enough bytes to read value of component 0)
```

here is how I created CF using CQLSH. I want to insert ("1","2","aaa") into "test".

CREATE COLUMNFAMILY test  (id1 varchar, id2 varchar, value varchar,PRIMARY KEY (id1,id2));

Here is my source code, anybody has any idea what's wrong here and how to make it work?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       

    TSocket socket = new TSocket("10.10.8.200", 9160);
    TFramedTransport transport = new TFramedTransport(socket);

    Cassandra.Client client = new Cassandra.Client(new TBinaryProtocol(transport));     
    transport.open();
    client.set_cql_version("3.0.0");
    client.set_keyspace("bigdata");

    ColumnParent parent = new ColumnParent("test");

    List<AbstractType<?>> keyTypes = new ArrayList<AbstractType<?>>(); 
    keyTypes.add(UTF8Type.instance);
    keyTypes.add(UTF8Type.instance);
    CompositeType compositeKey = CompositeType.getInstance(keyTypes);

    Builder builder = new Builder(compositeKey);
    builder.add(ByteBuffer.wrap("1".getBytes()));
    builder.add(ByteBuffer.wrap("2".getBytes()));
    ByteBuffer rowid = builder.build();

    Column column = new Column();
    column.setName("value".getBytes());
    column.setValue("aaa".getBytes());
    column.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

    client.insert(rowid, parent, column, ConsistencyLevel.ONE);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. Going out on a limb here.  If you want the primary key to be composed of id1 and id2 in that order, then when you insert a row you'll add a single column for value and the row key and column name will be derived from the values of id1 and id2.

The row key will be the value of id1.

The column name for value will be a composite value consisting of the value for id1 ("1" in this case) and the name of column id2 ("id2" in this case).

At least that's what you'd have to do in Hector if you didn't use CQL directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried and I'm almost there. Except can't assign value to column "value". I've posted my new code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you get an error (runtime or compiler) and if so, which one?

Answer (score 0):

OK. Finally, I figured out how to insert into a ColumnFamily with a composite Key using thrift API. I have to say, this doesn't make any sense. But it works:

```
    ColumnParent parent = new ColumnParent("test");

    List<AbstractType<?>> keyTypes = new ArrayList<AbstractType<?>>(); 
    keyTypes.add(UTF8Type.instance);
    keyTypes.add(UTF8Type.instance);
    CompositeType compositeKey = CompositeType.getInstance(keyTypes);

    Builder builder = new Builder(compositeKey);
    builder.add(ByteBuffer.wrap("2".getBytes()));
    builder.add(ByteBuffer.wrap("value".getBytes()));
    ByteBuffer columnName = builder.build();


    Column column = new Column();
    column.setName(columnName);
    column.setValue("3".getBytes());
    column.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

    client.insert(ByteBuffer.wrap("1".getBytes()), parent, column, ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
```